# jQuery UI draggable not working properly in IE7. Works in IE8

Tags: css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have an issue with IE7 where the jQuery UI draggable is showing underneath the droppable instead of on top of it when dragging. The droppable is also a draggable.
The page works fine in IE8 and other browsers. I tried quirks and standards mode in IE7. Both experience the issue.

The droppable consists of two div's on top of each other, one shifted from the other using position jQuery utility function. The draggable should show on top of both.
The z-index of the draggable is set to a very high value to ensure it's on top of anything on the page. As a test during dragging I am setting and displaying the z-index of the div's in the droppable & the draggable and confirmed that the draggable has the highest z-index.

After some troubleshooting it seems `"position:relative"` is the culprit. When I remove the position function, the draggable shows on top. However I need it to position a few elements properly, specially the two div's which are on top of each other.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

(My html is quite complex to show here.)

```
**Addition:**
```

I tried positioning with position:absolute instead of using position(). Still no go.

Comment: Remember that through IE 4 to IE 7 the z-index property doesn't work properly. The z-index is set relative to the nearest positioned parent not relative to the page. In other words: in IE 7 and earlier, each positioned elements generates a new stacking order beginning with z-index of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parents of both are also set to position:relative, then you might need to set the z-index of the parents.